# how can i create smooth seeker in my video player like youtube player

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have created a player and I expected it to be smooth as a youtube player. But my player is not that smooth. and it also gives some bug-like
If I mouse down the slider and mousemove it and it slides but after mouse up, it doesn't stop the slide on mousemove and it doesn't give the same result I expected

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var music = document.getElementById('music');
    music.src = 'https://fr01.mp3snow.com/4d1c6fa75beebf67d9969/Charlie%20Puth%20-%20We%20Don%20t%20Talk%20Anymore%20feat.%20Selena%20Gomez.mp3'
    setTimeout(()=>{
    
        var play = document.getElementById('playpause')
    

    
    
        //slider for music
        var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
        //slider Container for slider in music player
        var sliderCon = document.getElementById('sliderCon');
        var clicked = false;
        var body = document.querySelector('body');
        var timer = document.getElementById('time');
        var durat = document.getElementById('duration');
        sliderCon.onmousedown = (e) => {
            music.currentTime = (e.offsetX/sliderCon.offsetWidth)*music.duration;
            clicked = true;
        }
        window.onmousemove = (e) =>{
            if(clicked == true){
                music.currentTime = (e.offsetX/sliderCon.offsetWidth)*music.duration;
                if(music.ended == true){
                    music.play()
                }
                body.style.cursor = 'grabbing' ;
            }
            window.onmouseup = () => {
                clicked = false;
                body.style.cursor = 'inherit';
                
            }
        }
        
        
        
        function timing(totaltime){
            if (totaltime>60){
                var minute = Math.floor(totaltime/60)
                var second = Math.floor(totaltime%60)
                if(minute>9){
                    var time;
                    if (second >9){
                        time = minute+':'+second;
                    }else{
                        time = minute+':'+'0'+second;
                    }
                }else if (minute<10){
                    var time;
                    if (second >9){
                        time = '0'+minute+':'+second;
                    }else{
                        time = '0'+minute+':'+'0'+second;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if (totaltime<10){
                    var time = '00:0'+Math.floor(totaltime)
                }else{
                    var time = '00:'+Math.floor(totaltime)
                }
            }
            return time;
        }


          music.ontimeupdate = () =>{
            var sliderWidth = (music.currentTime/music.duration)*100;
            slider.style.width = sliderWidth+'%';
        
            timer.innerHTML = timing(music.currentTime)
        
            durat.innerHTML = timing(music.duration)
        

        }
        
        
        
        
        
        play.onselect = () =>{
        document.click();
        }
        play.onclick = (e) => {
            if(music.paused == true || music.ended == true){
                music.play();
                play.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>';
            }else if (music.paused == false || music.ended == false){
                music.pause();
                play.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-play"></i>';
        
            }
        }
        
        window.onkeydown = (key) => {
            if (key.key == 'ArrowRight'){
                music.currentTime += 5
            }
            if (key.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
                music.currentTime -= 5
            }
            if (key.key == ' ') {
                if(music.paused == true || music.ended == true){
                    music.play();
                    play.innerHTML = 'PAUSE';
                }else if (music.paused == false || music.ended == false){
                    music.pause();
                    play.innerHTML = 'PLAY';
            
                } 
            }
            if (key.key == 'ArrowUp'){
        
                if(music.volume < 1){
                    music.volume +=0.1;
                }
            }
            if (key.key == 'ArrowDown'){
                if(music.volume > 0.1){
                    music.volume -=0.1;
                }
            }
            if (key.code == 'NumpadAdd'){
                if (music.playbackRate < 2.0){
                    music.playbackRate += 0.1
                }
            }
            if (key.code == 'NumpadSubtract'){
                if (music.playbackRate > 0.1){
                    music.playbackRate -= 0.1
                }
            }
            if (key.key == 'h'){
                music.playbackRate = -1.0;
            }
        }
    
    },0)
    var loaded = document.getElementById('loaded');
    console.log(loaded)
    music.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            loaded.style.width = Math.round((this.buffered.end(0)/this.duration) * 100)+'%';

        },6)
      });

      
    }
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: rgba(32, 29, 29, 0.89);
}
.playpause{
    color: rgb(255, 248, 248);
    left: 22%;
    position: relative;
    top: 16%;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#duration{
    color: rgb(255, 248, 248);
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: -1rem;

}
#time{
    color: rgb(255, 248, 248);
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    
}
#fornow{
    background-color: rgb(116, 116, 150);
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 150px;
    
}
.sliderCon{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(197, 192, 192);
    height: 6px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.slider{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: rgb(228, 54, 54);

}
.sliderCon:hover{
    height: 10px;
    top: 67px;
    cursor: grab;
}

.thumb{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 54, 54);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 98%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.sliderCon:hover .thumb{
    margin-left: 97%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#loaded{
    background-color: rgba(226, 95, 95, 0.616);
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
}
#loading{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: teal;
    transition: 1s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: load 1s infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    border-top-color: tomato;
    display: none;


}
@keyframes load{
    to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.yo{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px; 
    background-color: cyan;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <audio src="./" id="music"></audio>

    <div class="player">
        <div id="fornow">
            <div class="sliderCon"  id="sliderCon">
                <div id="loaded">
                </div>
                <div class="slider" id="slider">
                    <div class="thumb"  id="thumb"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div id="time">00:00</div>
            <div id="duration">00:00</div>
            <div id="loading">

            </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="backward"></div>
            <div class="yo">
            <div class="playpause" id="playpause"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></div>
        </div>
            <div class="forward"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is the Code You can run it and see that it is not smooth as youtube
and it is also declared that youtube player is not flash
so what is the secret of youtube players that I don't know?
Please tell me the answer if anyone knows. sorry This is my personal project so I didn't commented it or name it very well

### ***Thank You***